# Is there a way to use the column before and after a center column to do analysis?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I'm trying to do analysis on datasets that have a varying number of columns, but I need to use 3 columns per use of my equation.  I want to use all columns in my dataset (with the exception of the first and last as they will not work)  But I need to select a center column, the column before, and the column after.  I need to implement these equations:

```
lower_actual = lower_original - dark;
lower_avg = sum(lower_actual)/length(lower_actual);
lower_gain = lower_avg./lower_actual;

upper_actual = upper_original - dark;
upper_avg = sum(upper_actual)/length(upper_actual);
upper_gain = upper_avg./upper_actual;

middle_actual = middle_original - dark;

x1 = lower_actual;
x2 = middle_actual;
x3 = upper_actual;
y1 = lower_gain;
y3 = upper_gain;
y2 = (((x2-x1).*(y3-y1))./(x3-x1))+y1;
interpolate = y2.*middle_actual;
```

In these equations the variables correlate to:

```
lower = column before
middle = center column
upper = column after
dark = first column in data set
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you work on a matrix `M`, e.g.

```
M = randn(10, 7);
```

Just loop over the columns skipping the first one and the last one.

```
interpolate = zeros(size(M, 1), size(M, 2) - 2);
dark = M(:, 1);
% Loop over the columns. Do not use the first and the last column as
% center columns.
for idx = 2 : size(M, 2) - 2
    lower_original = M(:, idx);
    middle_original = M(:, idx + 1);
    upper_original = M(:, idx + 2);

    % Your computations.
    lower_actual = lower_original - dark;
    lower_avg = mean(lower_actual);
    lower_gain = lower_avg./lower_actual;

    upper_actual = upper_original - dark;
    upper_avg = mean(upper_actual);
    upper_gain = upper_avg./upper_actual;

    middle_actual = middle_original - dark;

    x1 = lower_actual;
    x2 = middle_actual;
    x3 = upper_actual;
    y1 = lower_gain;
    y3 = upper_gain;
    y2 = (((x2-x1).*(y3-y1))./(x3-x1))+y1;

    interpolate(:, idx - 1) = y2.*middle_actual;
end
```

The maximum column index which is fetched is `size(M, 2) - 3 + 2 == size(M, 2) - 1`, i.e. the last column will be skipped.

Comment: I think I may have been unclear, I need to do this for every column in the matrix. That is, I need to use all columns, except the first and last, as a center column and then find their respect before and after columns

Comment: Is this `size(M, 2) - 3 + 2 == size(M, 2) - 1` what causes the last sequence of calculations to be from columns 13,14,15 when i have a max 16 columns (in the data set im using to test this).  Since in reality Id want 14,15,16 to be the last set of columns used

Comment: @BenB.: I modified the code to not use the first and the last column as center columns but nonetheless include them in the computation. If this is also not what you want, please clarify the question.

Comment: It was fine with the fix you had commented before, since the first column is a dark level i wont use it to compare against the rest of the matrix, therefore 2 couldnt be a center was well (I just thought of this) but it is working perfectly now, I edited the answer to the solution for my needs

Answer (score 2):

You could use [HANKEL](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/hankel.html) function to generate all possible indices of all three consecutive columns (with the exception of the first and last ones):

Example:

```
>> X = rand(10,7);
>> idx = hankel((1:3)+1, 3+1:size(M,2)-1)
idx =
     2     3     4
     3     4     5
     4     5     6
```

Each column gives you the indices of before/middle/after of one combination of columns of X in that order:

```
interpolate = zeros(size(X,1), size(idx,2));
for i=1:size(idx,2)
    ind = idx(:,i);
    xLower = X(:,ind(1));
    xMiddle = X(:,ind(2));
    xUpper = X(:,ind(3));

    %# perform calculations
    interpolate(:,i) = ...;
end
```

Comment: So you're just using the X = rand(10,7); to generate an example matrix correct?  In my case i could just skip that and start using my varible for my matrix right?

Comment: @BenB.: yes, that was just to get an example matrix to work on

Comment: Is there a way to output each of the final calculations into their own separate variable or even just index them? because it looks like it's just over writing them right now and ending with the final 3 columns.  `interpolate = y2.*middle_actual;` is the variable i need stored separatly each time.

Comment: @BenB.: see my edit. You can store the result of each iteration in a matrix (since each is a column of the same size)

Comment: okay so it might not necessarily be an issue, but it isnt using the second to last column as a center.  The dataset I'm using currently (just to play around and get everything smoothed out) is 16 columns max.  it starts out using columns 2,3,4 to do the calculations which is fine, but it's ending with 13,14,15 when it should be 14,15,16.

Comment: @BenB.: That was intentional, I thought you said you wanted to skip the first and last columns? If not, use this line instead to generate the indices : `idx = hankel((1:3)+1, 3+1:size(M,2))` (includes the last column)

Comment: Ahh I was referencing the fact that the first and and last column couldnt be used as a center (as there is nothign before or after them)  But thank you